# Avoiding [process completed] prompt after terminal script ends on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

In my text editor, I have bound a shortcut key to deploy my code by invoking a command like

```
/usr/bin/open /Users/blahblah/run_deploy
```

That deploy script uploads my code to my server etc. I am using "open" so that I can see the output in a new terminal window in case there are any errors. Very convenient, but in the end it leaves the terminal window open with text "[Process completed]".

Any way to skip this and instead just automatically close the window?

[image: Terminal process completed]

Comment: Give that you've set Terminal to close the window when the shell exits, it sounds like a Terminal issue. Have you tried deleting the preference file `com.apple.Terminal.plist` from your Preferences folder and tried setting it again?

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In Terminal *Preferences*, in *Profiles* pane select the Profile you use (should say "default" under it's name), select sub-pane *Shell* and change «*When the shell exits:*» to «*Close if the shell exited cleanly*».

It will not hide the `[Process completed]` message, but will close the window if exit code was successful.

Comment: For some reason I cannot change the settings in that terminal window. If I change them in another terminal window and "use as default", still they are not used in the new terminal window. Here's what the new terminal window looks like: http://i.imgur.com/u3tk4.png

Comment: First to make testing faster run following: `echo 'say hello' > test; chmod +x test` (it will create executable which will say hello), running `open test` or double-clicking it in finder will run it with terminal by default.

On your screenshot none of schemes is selected (don't know how, I can't unselect all of them), so select Basic as it is marked «Default», and set closing setting, then try running script.

Comment: Thanks, but that also didn't work: http://i.imgur.com/cCo49.png

Comment: Which os version do you use (don't know if it can be related, I use 10.6.4)?

Maybe this is due unread mail? Try using `mail` to read it.

Maybe something wrong with logout? Do you have `~/.bash_logout` file, if yes, what is inside? Try running `bash -c exit && echo 'ok'` — you should see 'ok', also try just run `exit` in new shell — it should close the window.

Do you use window groups?

http://i.imgur.com/thPNV.png

Comment: Could you put a "killall Terminal" command at the end of your script or something?  I know that'll close the window no matter what, but you can at least watch what's going on DURING the script's run (and you could also push the output to a log, just in case).

Comment: I read all the mail and ok does display. Typing "exit" in new shell does exit. But still that "test" doesn't close the window on exit. I don't use window groups. I don't have a ~/.bash_logout file. OS is 10.5.8. @jrc03c I don't want to close all my terminals.

Comment: Does simply typing exit close window/tab? Try deleting preference file, as Chealion suggested. Try watching log through Console.app.

Comment: In 10.7 (Mountain Lion), I actually had to add "bash" to the list of processes in the Terminal Preferences so it would exit without asking for permission.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing permissions via the `Disk utility` app solved the problem for me.

I kept seeing the error in the `Console` app:

```
20/08/2015 01:17:42.318 login[3291]: in pam_sm_open_session(): Unable to write the utmp record.
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on my Mac was:

Terminal>Shell>Reset
or you can use the shortcut (Option+Command+R)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).